# Set icon position on Action bar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

[image]

How can I change the position of the image to the left? And why isn't the title being displayed?

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.image);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My playlist");
```

Comment: rebuild app then run again

Comment: Do you think this will work ?-_-

Comment: your problem seems like you added toolbarIcon, launched app, then added title and forgot to run again app... serious... Your code works for me so there must be another reason or this above.